# Client side event when using response.flush() in an iframe

Tags: events, iframe, flush

I have an iframe which is loading a page. I am using response.flush() on server side because html of iframe could be very large. Is there any event which is triggered on client side when response is flushed on server? I tried load,init but they are being called when all data is flushed.